# Subdomain 301 redirect (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

How could I redirect my subdomain to main domain name? For example, I would like to redirect media.www.example.com to www.example.com using htaccess 301 redirect.

Tried this, but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^media.www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, the subdomain looks like I have said: "media.www.example.com"

Comment: "But it's not working"-please define that.

Comment: It not redirects to www.example.com
I get this: Error while fetching URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://shop.example.com/test.htm[NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/test.htm[L,R=301,NC]
```

So your code will be like that....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.media.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```